# Un-pivoting data from Table

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a requirement to refine below data in a table structure like VIEW or Materialized VIEW. Please help on how to achieve it.

```
Employee  Manager  Management_Chain 
vp2221    bg7915   jd613hbs0712sm2389mw6143mc7580ab3793bg7915vp2221
bg7915    ab3793   jd613hbs0712sm2389mw6143mc7580ab3793bg7915
ab3793    mc7580   jd613hbs0712sm2389mw6143mc7580ab3793
rx2131    bg7915   jd613hbs0712sm2389mw6143mc7580ab3793bg7915rx2131
```

The requirement is to convert above data as below... adding a distance column  values (0,1,2,3,4,....) based on Employee and Management_Chain column. For each employee there is a management chain where employee ID is also part of Mgmt chain.

```
Employee     Manager   Distance   
vp2221       vp2221      0    
vp2221       bg7915      1    
vp2221       ab3793      2    
vp2221       mc7580      3   
vp2221       mw6143      4  
vp2221       sm2389      5    
vp2221       bs0712      6    
vp2221       jd613h      7    
bg7915       bg7915      0    
bg7915       ab3793      1   
bg7915       mc7580      2   
bg7915       mw6143      3   
bg7915       sm2389      4    
bg7915       bs0712      5    
bg7915       jd613h      6    
ab3793       ab3793      0   
ab3793       mc7580      1    
ab3793       mw6143      2    
ab3793       sm2389      3    
ab3793       bs0712      4    
ab3793       jd613h      5    
rx2131       vp2221      0   
rx2131       bg7915      1   
rx2131       ab3793      2    
rx2131       mc7580      3    
rx2131       mw6143      4    
rx2131       sm2389      5   
rx2131       bs0712      6    
rx2131       jd613h      7    
....
```

Comment: You really have the management chain as a single field against each employee, not just stored hierarchically - does that column actually exist? Are you sure this is the base data - you aren't looking at a view that has combined a hierarchy? How do you identify links in the chain - by 6-char chunks?

Comment: Yes, we have the management chain as a single field against each employee. It's a base data. each employee is 6 char long.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `unpivot` to do this -

```
select employee, val as manager, min_n as distance
from(
select employee,
       manager,
       case when length(management_chain)/6 >= 1 then substr(management_chain, length(management_chain) - 5, 6) end as min_00,
       case when length(management_chain)/6 >= 2 then substr(management_chain, length(management_chain) - 11, 6) end as min_01,
       case when length(management_chain)/6 >= 3 then substr(management_chain, length(management_chain) - 17, 6) end as min_02,
       case when length(management_chain)/6 >= 4 then substr(management_chain, length(management_chain) - 23, 6) end as min_03,
       case when length(management_chain)/6 >= 5 then substr(management_chain, length(management_chain) - 29, 6) end as min_04,
       case when length(management_chain)/6 >= 6 then substr(management_chain, length(management_chain) - 35, 6) end as min_05,
       case when length(management_chain)/6 >= 7 then substr(management_chain, length(management_chain) - 41, 6) end as min_06,
       case when length(management_chain)/6 >= 8 then substr(management_chain, length(management_chain) - 47, 6) end as min_07,
       case when length(management_chain)/6 >= 9 then substr(management_chain, length(management_chain) - 53, 6) end as min_08,
       case when length(management_chain)/6 >= 10 then substr(management_chain, length(management_chain) - 59, 6) end as min_09
  from tbl
) unpivot (
 val for (min_n) in
 (
   min_00 as 0,
    min_01 as 1,
     min_02 as 2,
      min_03 as 3,
       min_04 as 4,
        min_05 as 5,
         min_06 as 6,
          min_07 as 7,
           min_08 as 8,
            min_09 as 9
 )
);
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/99cc5/3/0

The above will work if the management_chain always has 10 or fewer employees. If there might be more you will need to add additional lines as appropriate. If there are fewer, that is not a problem, as you can see in the demo, as unpivot does not include nulls by default (and the case statements in the inline view ensure nulls are used in those cases).

Answer (score 0):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db119/10)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE NEEDS_REFACTORING ( Employee,  Manager,  Management_Chain ) AS
          SELECT 'vp2221','bg7915','jd613hbs0712sm2389mw6143mc7580ab3793bg7915vp2221' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'bg7915','ab3793','jd613hbs0712sm2389mw6143mc7580ab3793bg7915' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'ab3793','mc7580','jd613hbs0712sm2389mw6143mc7580ab3793' FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 'rx2131','bg7915','jd613hbs0712sm2389mw6143mc7580ab3793bg7915rx2131' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE,
       SUBSTR( MANAGEMENT_CHAIN, 6*COLUMN_VALUE - 5, 6 ) AS MANAGER,
       LENGTH(MANAGEMENT_CHAIN)/6 - COLUMN_VALUE AS DISTANCE
FROM   NEEDS_REFACTORING r,
       TABLE(
         CAST(
           MULTISET(
             SELECT LEVEL
             FROM   DUAL
             CONNECT BY 6*LEVEL <= LENGTH( r.MANAGEMENT_CHAIN )
           )
           AS SYS.ODCINUMBERLIST
         )
       )
ORDER BY 1,3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/db119/10/0)**:

```
| EMPLOYEE | MANAGER | DISTANCE |
|----------|---------|----------|
|   ab3793 |  ab3793 |        0 |
|   ab3793 |  mc7580 |        1 |
|   ab3793 |  mw6143 |        2 |
|   ab3793 |  sm2389 |        3 |
|   ab3793 |  bs0712 |        4 |
|   ab3793 |  jd613h |        5 |
|   bg7915 |  bg7915 |        0 |
|   bg7915 |  ab3793 |        1 |
|   bg7915 |  mc7580 |        2 |
|   bg7915 |  mw6143 |        3 |
|   bg7915 |  sm2389 |        4 |
|   bg7915 |  bs0712 |        5 |
|   bg7915 |  jd613h |        6 |
|   rx2131 |  rx2131 |        0 |
|   rx2131 |  bg7915 |        1 |
|   rx2131 |  ab3793 |        2 |
|   rx2131 |  mc7580 |        3 |
|   rx2131 |  mw6143 |        4 |
|   rx2131 |  sm2389 |        5 |
|   rx2131 |  bs0712 |        6 |
|   rx2131 |  jd613h |        7 |
|   vp2221 |  vp2221 |        0 |
|   vp2221 |  bg7915 |        1 |
|   vp2221 |  ab3793 |        2 |
|   vp2221 |  mc7580 |        3 |
|   vp2221 |  mw6143 |        4 |
|   vp2221 |  sm2389 |        5 |
|   vp2221 |  bs0712 |        6 |
|   vp2221 |  jd613h |        7 |
```